# styling form render in Django

Tags: django, django-templates

I'm using `Django 2.x`

I'm using `Formset` to be able to add multiple records at one.

the form is rendered in `template` file as

```
{{ chapter_questions.as_table }}
```

Which renders template like below which looks ugly.

[image]

I'm using `Bootstrap` template to design my template to look like

[image]

To render template like second image, I'm writing the fields manually as

```
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
        <label for="question">Word</label>
            <input name="chapterquestion_set-0-word" type="text" class="form-control border-color-2" placeholder="Word" id="question">

            {% if chapterquestion_set.word.errors %}
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-12">
                    <div class="alert alert-danger">
                        <ul>
                            {% for error in chapter_questions.word.errors %}
                            <li>{{ error }}</li>
                            {% endfor %}
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        {% endif %}

    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
        <label for="definition">Definition</label>
        <input name="chapterquestion_set-0-definition" type="text" class="form-control border-color-3" placeholder="Definition" id="definition">

        {% if chapter_questions.definition.errors %}
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12">
                <div class="alert alert-danger">
                    <ul>
                        {% for error in chapter_questions.definition.errors %}
                        <li>{{ error }}</li>
                        {% endfor %}
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        {% endif %}
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
        <label for="audio"></label>
        <input name="chapterquestion_set-0-audio" type="text" class="form-control border-color-4" placeholder="Audio" id="audio">

        {% if chapter_questions.audio.errors %}
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12">
                <div class="alert alert-danger">
                    <ul>
                        {% for error in chapter_questions.audio.errors %}
                        <li>{{ error }}</li>
                        {% endfor %}
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        {% endif %}
    </div>
</div>
```

This way I have to write the code multiple times for multiple objects. Also for adding a new object fields, I need to replicate whole code using JavaScript by replacing index number (0 in this case) by updating by 1.

How can I style the form widget so that I could take benefit of Django automatic field insertions and error display and only need `{{ chapter_questions.as_bootstrap_div }}` to render bootstrap form.

Comment: did you try adding {{ chapter_questions.as_table }} inside <table> </table> tag?

Comment: but I do not want to use table to render form. I want to use Bootstrap's div col to render form.

Comment: How can I create global file to render text fields and other fields so that the custom styling is rendered. just like it do with `as_table` tag

Comment: you can add html classes to the form fields when defining the Form/ModelForm

Comment: But, after looking at level of customization you have to do, I suggest creating templates for each field type and use it

Comment: Try using django-crispy-forms (http://django-crispy-forms.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

Comment: how to create template for each field type. I would prefer creating template for each field because it will be used throughout the website and thus it would not require adding class in each field in model or form.

Comment: I have given an idea on using templates for fields below

Answer (score 0):

templates/fields/text-field.html

```
<div class="col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
    {{field.label_tag}}
    <input name="{{field.name}}" type="text" class="form-control border-color-2" placeholder="{{field.label}}" id="{{field.name}}">

    {% if field.errors %}
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            <div class="alert alert-danger">
                <ul>
                    {% for error in field.errors %}
                    <li>{{ error }}</li>
                    {% endfor %}
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    {% endif %}
</div>
```

on your form

```
{% with chapterquestion_set.word as field %}
    {% include 'fields/text-field.html' %}
{% endwith %}
```

Comment: isn't there someway to use it like `formset.as_custom` just like `formset.as_table` ?

Comment: not really. trying crispy-forms as @Serafeim suggested if you don't want to do this